# How to process the SOAPPRIMITIVE response

Tags: android, wcf, json, ksoap

I have WCF method that return String type.

This is my output

> {"Table1" : [{"TableName" :
>   "LoadDistributor","Description" :
>   "Distributor ","MandatoryFlag" :
>   "1","Status" : "","Priority" :
>   "0"},{"TableName" :
>   "LoadPrice","Description" : "Price
>   ","MandatoryFlag" : "1","Status" :
>   "","Priority" : "0"},{"TableName" :
>   "LoadProduct","Description" : "Product
>   ","MandatoryFlag" : "1","Status" :
>   "","Priority" : "0"},{"TableName" :
>   "LoadTradeSchemeDetail","Description"
>   : "TradeSchemeDeta","MandatoryFlag" :
>   "1","Status" : "","Priority" :
>   "0"},{"TableName" :
>   "RD.AlternativeProductDetail","Description"
>   : "AltProdutDetail","MandatoryFlag" :
>   "0","Status" : "","Priority" :
>   "0"},{"TableName" :
>   "RD.AlternativeProductHeader","Description"
>   : "AltProdutHeader","MandatoryFlag" :
>   "0","Status" : "","Priority" :
>   "0"},{"TableName" :
>   "RD.BatchPriceDetail","Description" :
>   "BatchPrice ","MandatoryFlag" :
>   "1","Status" : "","Priority" :
>   "0"},{"TableName" :
>   "RD.Executive","Description" :
>   "Executive ","MandatoryFlag" :
>   "1","Status" : "","Priority" :
>   "0"},{"TableName" :
>   "RD.Route","Description" : "Route
>   ","MandatoryFlag" : "1","Status" :
>   "","Priority" : "0"},{"TableName" :
>   "RD.vwRetailer","Description" :
>   "Retailer ","MandatoryFlag" :
>   "1","Status" : "","Priority" :
>   "0"},{"TableName" :
>   "RD.vwRouteDetail","Description" :
>   "RouteDetail ","MandatoryFlag" :
>   "1","Status" : "","Priority" :
>   "0"},{"TableName" :
>   "XA.vwProductType","Description" :
>   "Brand Product C","MandatoryFlag" :
>   "1","Status" : "","Priority" :
>   "0"},{"TableName" :
>   "XA.vwTown","Description" : "Town
>   ","MandatoryFlag" : "1","Status" :
>   "","Priority" : "0"}]}

This is my Soap processing method

```
    // ksoap2 calling wcf
public SoapPrimitive soapPrimitive(String METHOD_NAME, String SOAP_ACTION, String NAMESPACE, String URL) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    SoapPrimitive responses = null;
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); //set up request
    request.addProperty("strExec", "7067");
    request.addProperty("strBusinessUnit", "HEMA");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); //put all required data into a soap envelope
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);  
    AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);  
    httpTransport.debug = true; 

    try{

        Log.w("Log_cat" ,"*********" + envelope.toString());
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        Log.w("log_tag", " ===========" +SOAP_ACTION );

        // Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse();
        // JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result.toString());
        // Log.w("log_tag", " ===*********==" +jArray );

         responses = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   // Object response= envelope.getResponse();
    return responses;
 }
```

My C# method return String with JSON( as a String).

How to get the Table name only in the List or Array.
Please help me .What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you understand the difference between SOAP and JSON? kSOAP is for processing services expecting SOAP request and returning SOAP response. So unless you have SOAP service returning single string element with JSON you don't need (and cannot use) kSoap. If you have REST service returning JSON use simple `DefaultHttpClient` and `HttpPost` as [described for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167341/how-to-pass-json-array-as-parameter-to-a-webservice-using-ksoap2-in-android). If you are using JSON all the time it also answers your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596131/android-consume-wcf-that-particular-method-return-datatable).

Comment: Its very helpful suggestion. In My case WCF service returning String element with JSON.

Comment: In my case I want to use SOAP, but its return String element with JSON. Now the result is coming correct way how to get the values?please help me.

Comment: Please guide me How to process SOAP value like this: {"Table1" : [{"TableName" : "LoadDistributor","Description" : "Distributor ","MandatoryFlag" : "1","Status" : "","Priority" : "0"}]}

Comment: Here you have some tutorials how to work with JSON in Android: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html , http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/

Comment: Thanks Ladislav. Its very helpful link